# Can't update WordPress theme's PHP files using browser editor or FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, ftp, connection-timeout

I'm currently designing a website in WordPress, using a custom theme I've used for a number of other websites. I was working on it last night and everything was working perfectly fine, however today I've run in to an issues that's got me stumped.

I'm trying to update the .php files in my theme (e.g. footer.php, header.php, index.php, etc.) however when I try to update them in the WordPress editor (Appearance, editor) it times out. After I click 'Update File' the page loads for about 30 seconds then gives me a 'This site can't be reached, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' error. I also get this error when trying to update or add new pages or posts, which would seem like a database error, but I was under the impression that the theme files aren't connected to the database in any way?

I've tried uploading and overwriting the PHP files via FTP, but that also times out. I can upload files via FTP that don't overwrite anything, but I can't overwrite anything that's there.

I've also tried deactivating all plugins (Only 2 installed) but that didn't change anything.

I've no idea what the issue might be here. It's as if I don't have permission to overwrite or change any of the site's files or database entries but I'm not sure why.

GoDaddy is the host I'm using, using a non-managed wordpress installation. The site in question is actually a staging site, on the main site I am able to edit everything as usual.

Comment: have you contacted GoDaddy?

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is likely caused by a problem connecting to your Godaddy server, and Wordpress is not the culprit. To rule Wordpress out, turn on debug mode in wp-config.php with `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and check your php error log in CPanel.

If you can't find any errors and after you try [generic solutions for this problem](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/578937/this-webpage-is-not-available-err-connection-reset/) you should probably call Godaddy and ask them what's up.